# Microsoft Band 2 with Universal Windows app

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10-universal, microsoft-band

I'm new to to Universal Windows Platform and I'm having some trouble
with it. I was following this tutorial (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt573717.aspx), but got stuck. I succeeded in installing and
building this app but I can't seem to run it on my local machine. The only
options Visual Studio gives is: Device and Emulator.

[image: Run options]

I was able to run the microsoft band sdk samples because
then I could select to run on my local machine. It is probably something stupid
but why can't I run this app on my local machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you must change the architecture from **ARM** to x86 or x64, or Any CPU.

[image]

Or in worst case you can "Download new emulators", but since you could run it locally with the Band-app samples, I assume they are already installed and you just need to quickly switch the architecture :)

Please remember to close your threads by marking helpful posts as answer and then start a new thread if you have a new question. Please don't ask several questions in the same thread.